# jQuery range slider without default CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

As it possible to not to download to project folder jQuery UI files?
Just added this link to my html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and this to my js file:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#price-filter" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#price-filter" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
```

It shows in Inspector that I have jquery slider inside my div, but it doesn't show content because there is no styles for it. How to display slider for customizing without downloading default files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use JQuery's CDN for CSS then try https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

It's used on their example https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Alternatively you can use the following CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui